# Why does ] not displayed in C?

Tags: c, format-specifiers

This is my code snippet in C:

```
      char *str = NULL;
      int len = -1;

      // Get length
      len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "[%d]", 2);

      // Allocate str
      str = (char *)malloc(len + 1);

      // Assign str
      snprintf(str, len, "[%d]", 2);

      assert(len == 3);

      // Display str
      puts(str);
```

I expect this should display `[2]`. And `len` here is 3.

But running this code displays only `[2`

Why is this so?

Comment: Please [don't cast the return value of `malloc()` in C](http://stackoverflow.com/a/605858/28169).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The length of the buffer is `len+1`, but you only pass `len` to `snprintf`, try this:

```
snprintf(str, len + 1, "[%d]", 2);
```

from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/snprintf/):

> If the resulting string would be longer than n-1 characters, the
>   remaining characters are discarded and not stored, but counted for the
>   value returned by the function.
>
> A terminating null character is automatically appended after the
>   content.

Comment: Yes. This answer is correct and will be accepted after 6 minutes. "You can accept an answer in 6 minutes".

Answer (score 0):

The functions snprintf() write at most len bytes (including the terminating null byte ('\0')) to str.

len equal to 3 (the first call), so snprintf will write only 3 char: '[', '2' and '\0'.